Question related to conservation of energy
Here is a textbook passage that I have trouble understanding. It is taken from Classical Mechanics by Tom WB Kibble and Frank H Berkshire.

We consider first a particle moving along a line, under a force which is given as a function of its position, $F(x)$. Them the equation of motion is
$$m\ddot x = F(x) \tag{2.1}$$
Since this equation is of second order in the time derivatives, we shall have to integrate twice to find $x$ as a function of $t$. Thus the solution will contain two arbitrary constants that may be fixed by specifying the initial values of $x$ and $ẋ$.
When the force depends only on $x$, we can always find a ‘first integral’, a function of $x$ and $ẋ$ whose value is constant in time. Let us consider the kinetic energy,
$$T= \frac 12 m\dot x^2 \tag{2.2}$$
Differentiating, we find for its rate of change
$$\dot T=m\dot x \ddot x = F(x) \dot x \tag{2.3}$$
using (2.1). Integrating with respect to time, we find
$$T=\int F(x) \dot x dt = \int F(x) dx \tag{2.4}$$
If we define the potential energy,
$$V(x) = - \int_{x_0}^x F(x')dx'\tag{2.5}$$
we can write (2.4) in the form
$$T + V = E = \text{constant} \tag{2.6}$$
Here $x_0$ is an arbitrary constant, corresponding to the arbitrary additive constant of integration in (2.4). There is a corresponding
arbitrariness up to an additive constant in the total energy $E$.

I don't get how step (2.5) or definition of potential energy allows us to rewrite step (2.4). I would like a step by step explanation. Although I am already familiar with conservation of energy the way it is presented in this book seems to trip me off.

$T$ can be written as
$$
\int_{x_0}^x F(x') dx' + C
$$
where $C$ is constant since equation $(2.4)$ is indefinite integral.
Put $C=E$, we can derive equation $(2.5)$

This is also new approach for me and it looks so freshy!

Thanks. Great job

I have a small doubt. I don't know much of integral calculus. So are you writing an indefinite integral as the sum of a definite integral and a constant?

Of course but let me look at this closely. Let $F=\int f dx$(this is definition of definite integral). Then the definite integral $\int_a^x dx' f(x')=F(x)-F(a)$. Reconstruct $F(x)$, $F=\int_a^x f(x')dx'+F(a)$. So, we have one constant left($F(a)$), we can call this as integral constant.

This is just about mathematics, but take a look at different POV in physics. What is the integral constant in this case? What is the point $x_0$? This is some thoughtful question among this energy conservation concept.

A conservative force can be written as follows: 
$$F=-\nabla V$$
meaning that we can plug the above expression in (2.4), which results in: 
$$T=\int -\nabla V dr$$
which equals to:
$$ T=-V+const $$
where $const$ is just a constant of integration, rearranging the expression gives the wanted result: 
$$ T+V=const $$
